# show mailto link to name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on AngularJs app where I need to show Name of customer but it should mail to link with email to his email address.
Eg : If name is `Bob` and email is `bob@a.com` , then on click of Bob it should show mail to `bob@a.com`

my html as as below

```
<div class="form-group mg-t20" ng-hide="!groupObj.accountExecutiveName">
            <label class="wd50p control-label left fw-norm">Account Executive:</label>
            <div class="wd48p blue-txt">
                {{groupObj.accountExecutiveName}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

I do have email property . Its `groupObj.accountExecutiveEmail` . How do i do this in html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work in your case:

```
<a ng-href="mailto:{{ groupObj.accountExecutiveEmail }}" target="_blank"> 
  {{ groupObj.accountExecutiveName }}
</a>
```

So your final HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="form-group mg-t20" ng-hide="!groupObj.accountExecutiveName">
    <label class="wd50p control-label left fw-norm">Account Executive:</label>
    <div class="wd48p blue-txt">
        <a ng-href="mailto:{{ groupObj.accountExecutiveEmail }}" target="_blank"> 
        {{ groupObj.accountExecutiveName }}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can add something like this to your template:

```
 <a ng-href="mailto:{{groupObj.accountExecutiveEmail}}" target="_blank">
     {{groupObj.accountExecutiveName}} --> here will be the item's name
 </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`mailto:` in an `<a>` tag is the way to go.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links

```
<a href="mailto:bob@a.com">Bob</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [mailto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links) link

```
<a ng-href="mailto:{{groupObj.accountExecutiveEmail}}">Send email</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular2+:

```
<a [href]="'mailto:' + groupObj.accountExecutiveEmail" target="_blank">Send mail</a>
```